# How to stop loading placeholder and show div in Jquery/CSS

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

I'm using css and jquery to load page with placeholder loading..
I have set is: 2 seconds to remove placeholder loading:

```js
$('body').append('<div id="linear-background"></div>');
  $(window).on('load', function(){
    setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
  });
  function removeLoader(){
   $( "#linear-background" ).fadeOut(500, function() {
     // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
     $( "#linear-background" ).remove(); //makes page more lightweight      
    });  
  }
```

```css
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer{
   0%{
    background-position: -468px 0
   }
   100%{
    background-position: 468px 0
   }
  }

  #linear-background {
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   background: #f6f7f8;
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
   background-size: 1000px 104px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .showText {
   background-color: red;   
   border: 1px solid #000;
   width: 100px;
   height: 10%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showText">Hello</div>
```

When load page first, I wish placeholder will show first and then remove it and show div later...

How to when placeholder loading finish, tag div will show later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First keep `display:none` to your div and when loader finishes you can show it. Go through my code or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzyRpj)

HTML Code-

```
<div class="showText">Hello</div>
```

CSS Code-

```
@keyframes placeHolderShimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -468px 0
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 468px 0
  }
}

#linear-background {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: placeHolderShimmer;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: #f6f7f8;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #eeeeee 8%, #dddddd 18%, #eeeeee 33%);
  background-size: 1000px 104px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.showText {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10%;
  display: none;
}
```

JS Code-

```
$('body').append('<div id="linear-background"></div>');
$(window).load(function() {
  setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
});

function removeLoader() {
  $("#linear-background").fadeOut(500, function() {
    // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
    $("#linear-background").remove(); //makes page more lightweight 
    $('.showText').show();
  });
}
```

Comment: If it's work for you then please up vote my answer as well as mark it as accepted answer. @HaLeViet

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the 'showText' div using [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). Then when your callback is called. you can call 'toggle' again to show it.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VVaNed)

Code here:

```
$('body').append('<div id="linear-background"></div>');
        $('.showText').toggle();
        $(window).on('load', function(){
          setTimeout(removeLoader, 2000); //wait for page load PLUS two seconds.
        });
        function removeLoader(){
            $( "#linear-background" ).fadeOut(500, function() {
              // fadeOut complete. Remove the loading div
              $( "#linear-background" ).remove(); //makes page more lightweight               
            $('.showText').toggle();
          });  
        }
```

Comment: instead of using an external snippet use SO built in snippet use `<>`